# How to reference a ListBox name using a string in Csharp

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox-control

```
for (int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    string buttonName = "button" + i;
    if (Controls[buttonName].BackColor = Color.Red)
    {
        Controls[buttonName].Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly.  The code checks 3 different buttons (button1, button2, button3) and if their color is red they become disabled. The button name is referenced using a string:

```
Controls[buttonName]
```

Is there a way to reference a ListBox using a string in the same way? What would "Controls" need to be changed to?

Comment: You would still use controls, but cast the item as a ListBox.  You can do as follows:

`var myListBox = Controls["ListBox1"] as ListBox;
//now you can do something to the ListBox object`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to reference a GroupBox with a string in this same way?

Comment: Yes it would just be `var myGrpBox = this.Controls["GroupBox1"] as GroupBox;`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to go over all ListBoxes, you could also use `.OfType<T>()`

```
foreach (ListBox lb in this.Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
{
    lb.Enabled = false;
}
```

... and it would of course work the same for `.OfType<Button>()` without the need to name your controls in a way to enumerate them.

Comment: Cheers! Good thinking